# Returning Value From JS Closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I am currently trying to understand closures but there is something which I don't seem to get no matter how many videos or forum posts I check.

As an example, here is a simple closure with a `parentFunction` and a `childFunction`:

```
function parentFunction(a, b) {
    function childFunction() {
        return a + b;
    }
    return childFunction;
}
```

What I don't understand is why is it necessary to assign the `parentFunction` to a variable and call it if I want the value returned from the `childFunction`:

`let test = parentFunction(1, 2)`

`console.log(test())`;

If I called the parent function directly, shouldn't it have the same outcome? For example:

`console.log(parentFunction(1, 2))`;

Isn't it the same as assigning it to the variable first but with an extra step? Is it just because of the syntax being that way and that's it?

Comment: `parentFunction` returns another function. You'd get the same output if you called the returned function:
`console.log(parentFunction(1,2)())`

Comment: @CertainPerformance That is not what is happening though, at least according to Chrome's console, when logging the variable, it returns the value of the `childFunction` (in this case it returns 3) but if I log the `parentFunction` directly I get the whole `childFunction` statement and not the returned value. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: in `let test = parentFunction(1, 2)`, test is not a variable, it is a function...

Comment: @MisterJojo Maybe I phrased that incorrectly but am I not declaring the variable test and assigning the value (which in this case is a function) to it?

Comment: declaring a new javascript element by assigning it a function, in javascript this means declaring a function  . have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262667/is-this-really-considered-a-javascript-closure/58263202#58263202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put it into a variable first, you're also *invoking* it when logging the result.

```
let test = parentFunction(1, 2)
console.log(test());
//              ^^
```

Substituting in `parentFunction(1, 2)` and removing the `test` variable entirely would be equivalent

```
console.log(test                ()); // before
console.log(parentFunction(1, 2)()); // after
```

But your second version lacks the `()` at the end, which is why it's not the same.

```
console.log(parentFunction(1, 2)()); // after
//                              ^^ your second version lacks this
```

`parentFunction` returns a function. You must call the function to get the resulting number from it, otherwise you have just the function.

Comment: there is a very famous question about closures, I guess there is no need in answering  this one

Comment: @dippas it's nice that he got a specific answer, he maybe just got confused. no link-only answer would help in this case

Comment: @CertainPerformance OMG so that's what was happening... Damn, I didn't even see it haha. Now this makes perfect sense, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @dippas As for the post you suggested, thanks but I did take a look at it and since in their examples they also assigned the function to a variable, It didn't help with this issue I had. Cheers!